# Objects in entire project can no longer be edited

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode, select

When I RMB-click on any object in my project, it no longer gets a yellow profile that indicates that it is selected. However, in the Scene panel on the right, it does appear in yellow. I can also perform transformations (move, rotate, scale) on the "selected" object.

However, when I go into Edit Mode (see picture), the view of the "selected" object doesn't change, whereas normally it should change to either a vertex, edge or face view. The Editing interface does appear, but since there are no vertices, edges or faces to select, it's useless.

Did I inadvertently lock or deactivate a functionality in Blender?

[image]

Comment: You've disabled overlays. Look at the button top right of the 3d view.

Comment: This is starting to become embarring. Thanks, again, @lemon

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate *Show Overlays*.

[image]